# Azure Functions: The binding type(s) 'eventHubTrigger' are not registered

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-functions-runtime

I have created an Azure Function to store messages from Azure IoT Hub to Table Storage using built endpoint of EventHub of IoT Hub. I am using Azure Functions v2(.Net Standard) for creating the EventHubTrigger functions.I developed the function and tested it locally and it is working as required. But when I am hosting this function in Azure, it shows the following error in the portal:

### Error: The binding type(s) 'eventHubTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.

I have already installed the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs -v 3.0.0-beta4 nuget package in the code.

Can someone help with this error as nothing much is mentioned regarding this in the docs.

Following are the packages installed in the solution:

1. Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.13
2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs 3.0.0-beta4
3. NETStandard.Library v2.0.3

Comment: Had the same Error: The binding type(s) 'eventHubTrigger' are not registered. locally. Update for packages related to Azure helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different behavior is caused by old `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools` in VS, which means VS still consumes old function templates and cli.

Just update VS2017 to [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#visual-studio-2017-version-158-releases)(15.8.6 right now) and go to VS menus>Tools>Extensions and Updates, find `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`, update it to [latest version](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md#release-notes)(15.10.2009.0 right now).

After steps of update, new EventHub trigger template works with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` 1.0.22 and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs` 3.0.0. And the function cli is

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.3)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12115.0
```